# Why can't I add values to my table? a simple question i guess

Tags: sql, sql-server

my first question here. Its about MS SQL, and I am writing in SSMS v18.10
I guess I shouldn't be posting such a simple question, but i am getting discouraged from trying further.
This is my Table, with 4 columns
[image: table]

as you can see I am trying to enter 2 simple records, with entering the 4 names of the columns and I get this error:
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

And if i change it to no column names I just get a different error:
[image: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.]

Why can't I just add the values with the code? Sorry if i formated the post wrong, its my first try.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't think the `INSERT` in the first screenshot ran either; you only highlighted the `SELECT` statement, so I suspect that was all that was ran.

Comment: yes, on the first screen, I wanted to show how the table looks, to explain it a bit more

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert one row with eight columns into a table with four columns.

You need to wrap the values for each row in separate parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO Tabela_produkt (ID, Typ, Producent, Model)
VALUES
    ('1', '...', 'MSI', 'geforce'),
    ('2', '...', '...', '...')
;
```

Comment: Ok, i see that now. it worked. glad there is this place

Answer (score 1):

```
 INSERT Tabela_produkt(id,typ,producent,model)
        values(1,'karta graficzna','msi','geforce'),
              (2,'karta graficzna','asus','radeon');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clearly separate the rows you are inserting, each one having four values. For example:

```
insert into tabela_produckt (ID, Typ, Producent, Model)
values
  ('1', 'karta1', 'MSI', 'geforce'),
  ('2', 'karta2', 'ASUS', 'Radeon');
```

Comment: thank you, i see it now, such a silly little detail